# invalid template compilation

Tags: android, cgal, toolchain, libc++

I am including CGAL headers in my android library and I am getting this error. I am not using CGAL::Epick myself, and it is a type that is templatized in CGAL. This does not appear to be a CGAL specific issue ( it might be) but can be a toolchain/libc++ issue that Android C++ experts may help me with. Please comment.

```
In file included from /home/ypv/gazebo_dev/240GB/android-ndk-samples/android-dso-server/app/src/main/cpp/dso_server/planning/planning_server/dStar/navGraph.cpp:1:
  In file included from /home/ypv/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/string:470:
  In file included from /home/ypv/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/string_view:169:
  In file included from /home/ypv/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__string:56:
  In file included from /home/ypv/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/algorithm:643:
  In file included from /home/ypv/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/memory:650:
  In file included from /home/ypv/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/iterator:427:
  /home/ypv/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__functional_base:60:21: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const CGAL::Epick' and 'const CGAL::Epick')
          {return __x < __y;}
```

Comment: There is something fishy here. Who is trying to compare two kernel instances?

Comment: Aee you saying, no direct kernel comparison takes place inside CGAL?

Comment: A kernel is not something you compare. But with the information you provided, we can't say more than "there is a problem".

Comment: This error happens as soon as there is an include of CGAL header and an include of an stl header, e.g. vector or string or map, etc. I recompiled CGAL header only, to eliminate any doubt wrt stdc++. As this is a compilation error, linking to the wrong stl library does not seem to apply.

Comment: @ypvvpy Your question is really badly formulated. You should give some context, about the piece of code you are trying to compile.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. In fact the compiler was looking for the CGAL::Epick comparison operator that did not exist per codebase where CGAL kernels were being added implicitly to stl structures, e.g. vector and map. The structures were being iterated C++11 style, via an incorrect copy instead of a reference:

```
//not
for (auto: vectorOfStructsContainingEpickSets)
//but
for (auto&:vectorOfStructsContainingEpickSets)
```

These structures were deep-copied as a result, and when you deep-copy a struct containing an std::set, where the object itself is the key, inequality operator is called, i.e. epick is compared. Different derivatives of epics were stored in this way.

Yes, the answer to this question was ultimately, CGAL kernels should not be compared, even implicitly.

What is still unknown is why gcc-5 x86_64 linux compiled codebase did not complain where epick error happened in clang android x86_64 toolchain cross compilation.

Comment: This solution is limited in scope. I still need to be able to store CGAL kernels in vectors and other containers. Experienced CGAL users, please help to understand why CGAL types are not easily copied into stl containers.

Comment: I suspect that CGAL types actually work okay with STL containers. I may be dealing with a modified CGAL library and some of the CGAL types have been augmented, i.e. added members.

Comment: It vectorEpicks really a vector ? because from the look of the original error it looks like a sorted container that needs a comparator, like a set. Anyway, why would you need to store Kernel instances ? Two instances of a same kernel are really the same actually.

Comment: In my case, structs derived from epicks contained additional information and that was the difference between two epicks. Why they were stored in a set without any way for differentiation, I have no idea.